# Dynamic variable inside angular @Component decorator

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-components, angular2-animation, angular2-decorators

I would like to pass dynamic variable to angular `@Component` class decorator.

As you can see from example there is a list of items.
I would like each item to be initially rotated with different degree -**`${DYNAMIC_DEGREE_VAR}`**.

If I set transform to random value directly: `rotate(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 + 1)}deg)` - each item will have **same** random value.

Any tips appreciated.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-list',
    templateUrl: 'my-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my-list.component.css']
})
export class MyListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: ItemModel[] = [];
}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-item',
    templateUrl: 'my-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my-item.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('itemState', [
            state('inactive', style({
                transform: `rotate(${DYNAMIC_DEGREE_VAR}deg)`
            })),
            state('active', style({
                transform: `rotate(0deg)`
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
            transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
})
export class MyItemComponent implements OnInit {

   item: ItemModel;

   state: string = 'inactive';
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// my-item.component.html
<div [@itemState]="state"></div>

// my-list.component.html
<my-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let items of item"></my-item>
```

Comment: have you tried using this `transform:rotate(${this.DYNAMIC_DEGREE_VAR}deg)` and provide `DYNAMIC_DEGREE_VAR` in your class

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes. Sadly, decorators have no access to class properties.

Comment: ohh no idea sorry :(

Comment: I'm able to use a const outside of my class and decorator but like alex mentioned it doesn't work with class properties.